# Is there a way to stop running of Before Hooks in Playwright

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, playwright

I am writing testcases for an Organization which only uses Google for Authentication. But we can't automate Google Authentication with Playwright. So I am trying to Build a Test which runs a Browser which User Opened and Authenticated in it. So after that he can run the Tests.

Thus I thought of designing a Testcase in Typescript where I intend to Open a Browser Log In and Then I want to run the Test Case on the Same Browser. But, due to the Before Hooks the Tab in which I logged in is reloaded.

Consider the Below Example where I open a Playwright Browser and Navigate to Google Manually, then I write a Test Case which Searches for Apple by Typing Apple in the Search Bar which was previously loaded manually. I have written a Test Case for Searching but it always fails as the Tab is reloaded before the execution of actual test body.

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('LinkedinLoginTestCase', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.getByLabel('Search', { exact: true }).click();
  await page.getByLabel('Search', { exact: true }).fill('Apple');
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Apple - Official Site apple.' }).click();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. Please [edit] to clarify, preferably with a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: To be specific, I am writing a Test Case which has to Login to the Application before other Steps. The Problem here is the Application doesn't support Password Login and Only Allows Logging in Through Google.

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#session-storage you can try this. @ggorlen. he is trying to use a browser where login is already done. so test does not need to perform login as its google authentication which cannot be automated.. something on these lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362982/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-my-existing-browser-session-using-playwright

Comment: I understand that, but what's the problem/question? Login manually, without automation, store the session in a `userDataDir`, reference the `userDataDir` from the test config, and you should be good to go. There's no specific question here and I don't understand why the hooks pose any problem--there's no need to run your test suite to log in manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved if you open a browser which has profile and login is not required.Like it happen when you open a website in your own browser.

Check the link in the last explaining the same in detail

Same can be achieved if you open the browser loading a particular profile

```
browser = playwright.chromium.connect_over_cdp("http://localhost:9222")
```

Before above you can lunach the browser like

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Source :- -Though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431084/2986279) is for python approach remains the same even if you do the same thing in selenium